# Islands strategy Game Base Distance

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating a strategy game in Java, for which I am now writing a map editor. Before the game starts, the player makes a map with a number of islands and a number of resources on each island. After saving the map, the number of players is chosen. Each player has a base, and the bases must be located at the farthest distance from each other.

So, suppose I load a map with 5 islands and have 2 players when the game starts – each player must have one island. These islands must be at the largest distance from each other, so it should be like this: player 1's island, neutral island, neutral island, neutral island, player 2's island.

I have no idea what my algorithm should be for this.

Comment: Is the number of players and islands going to be large? You could brute-force it pretty simply if not, by checking all combinations to choose `k` items out of `n` (where `k` is the number of players and `n` is the number of islands), for small `k` and `n` - it could be done very quickly, no need to overthink it. Check for "generate all combinations of k out of n" there are plenty of examples for it.

Comment: I not I am not a mod, but I never understood why close a question that can be clarified so fast without asking questions. With few questions, and if the OP is responsive, the question can be turned into a solid one pretty quickly.

Comment: I agree with amit and voting to reopen. I think this question is not too broad, it's quite specific and could be clarified with couple of questions in the comments.

Comment: A map is 2D; your proposed solution for 5 islands is 1D (a line). Even if you consider a string of islands a 'line' if you connect them by their smallest distances, you still may end up with the end points being quite close. I think I agree with @amit: just calculate the distance of *every* island to *every other* island.

Comment: I think that a much smarter solution will revolve around the fact that you can calculate these distances while the person is creating these islands on the map editor. I don't have the time to think of one now, but will update you later if I come up with a specific algorithm

Comment: What do you think about this - each island will have a vector with all of the distances to the other islands. When a player chooses an island, all other islands will set their distance to that island to 0.
Then, the next player will be put at the island with the highest sum of all distances to the other islands. To make this dynamic you can calculate the total distance while adding the islands and use the vector to retrieve the distance which will be subtracted (the used island which is set to 0). This is quadratic time `n(n-1)` + it can be done during creation or post-creation of map

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to be equivalent to this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/choosing-a-subset-to-maximize-the-minimum-distance-between-points .  Solving this efficiently and exactly may be an open problem in theoretical CS!  Since this is for a game, I am not sure how much effort you want to solving this problem in an exactly optimal way.

It should be pretty easy, fast, and close to correct to generate a random guess and repeatedly (perturb it, measure the badness of the perturbed guess, and if the perturbed guess's badness is better than the current guess make the perturbed guess the current guess).

As for what you consider the badness of a possible guess, my suggestion is "average (the distance to the closest player-inhabited island) across all player-inhabited islands".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your number of islands and your number of player are quite small, i think a simple exhaustive search would be the easiest and fastest to implement way to do it.

1. make a matrix that holds a distance from one island to each other islands. (only necessary
2. systematically iterate over all combinations of player placements, sum up each distances from one to all other players and store the the maximum

Comment: This isquadratic time for the traversing of the matrix multiplied by the number of different players